# Why I cannot compile source code on my phone?

Tags: android

After I clicked run it shown as below

```
[2011-02-23 22:12:06 - cas1] Uploading cas1.apk onto device '100082d63935'
[2011-02-23 22:12:15 - cas1] Failed to install cas1.apk on device '100082d63935': timeout
[2011-02-23 22:12:15 - cas1] Launch canceled!
```

Please help me solve this problem

Comment: What are you trying to do? What is cas1? How are you trying to compile? More information please.

Comment: Have you checked the option to allow non-market apps under settings applications?

Answer (score 0):

Is it an actual device or emulator? Is the app already installed from the market? If you should uninstall the market version. If its the emulator, that happens to me occasionally and restarting the emulator and waiting until the home screen appears usually fixes it.

Comment: -It run on actual device
-no, this app is still developing 

In emulator I can run it well but I wonder why I cannot run it on my device ?

Answer (score 0):

Try issuing the command "adb kill-server" from the command line and then "adb devices" to start it back up again.  Then try to deploy your apk again. I've had issues deploying to the Honeycomb emulator from Eclipse and the above fixed it.

Finally, if this doesn't work try installing the apk from the command line using adb install -r [your_apk].